# Implementing RLE into personal cloud . server

Tags: database, server, compression, cloud

I recently made my own server with Ubuntu. I was doing some research into data compression, and wanted to know if there is a way I could implement RLE or some other algorithm into it? Is this easy to do or does it require programming? I know some java / C++/C#.

Anything helps!

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: what do you mean by "implement RLE or some other algorithm into it". Did you know that most web servers will automatically perform gzip compression if the client program indicates it supports receiving compressed payloads?

Comment: No I did not! That's why I was asking on here I don't know much about data compression.

Comment: And by implement I mean, make it so my database instantly compresses files as they are uploaded

Comment: what "cloud" server are you running?

Comment: And by the way, btrfs supports transparent compression and can be used with Ubuntu.

Comment: Well I'm running my cloud with owncloud but I have another 90gbs of storage and 2gbs of ram left so I was trying to do some other stuff with it.